# Looping statements with input

Tags: python, loops

I have been trying to fix this code forever but I am unsuccessful, I am trying to make it that once you have answered. It will automatically restart the program and you can play again. However, after multiple attempts I have not been able to do this

```
question = input("Press 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors")
if question is 'r':
    print('I choose paper, I win!')
elif question is 's':
    print('I choose rock, I win!')
elif question is 'p':
    print('I choose scissors, I win!')

for restart in question:
    print(restart)
```

Comment: Please include the actual code instead of screenshots. And, are you getting any errors?

Comment: what is `restart` in your program?

Comment: @AKS It wasn't letting me insert my code without an error, so I had to resort to a screenshot. The code works perfectly, but when I try and restart it. It will display the input that the user made before instead of actually restarting the program

Comment: @WasiAhmad I tryed making "restart" a variable, But it only prints out what the input was that the user typed before

Comment: Just be sure to use python3 else it will lead to an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (True):
    question = input("Press 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors or press 'e' to exit:")
    if question is 'r':
        print('I choose paper, I win!')
    elif question is 's':
        print('I choose rock, I win!')
    elif question is 'p':
        print('I choose scissors, I win!')
    elif question is 'e':
        print('restart')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a code structure as follows.

```
while True:
    question = input("Press 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors")
    if question is 'r':
        print('I choose paper, I win!')
    elif question is 's':
        print('I choose rock, I win!')
    elif question is 'p':
        print('I choose scissors, I win!')

    if condition: # write your condition here to exit from loop
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
def restart():
    question = input("Press 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors")
    if question is 'r':
        print('I choose rock, I win!')
    elif question is 's':
        print('I choose scissors, I win!')
    elif question is 'p':
        print('I choose papers, I win!')
    else:
        print('wrong choice')


continuePlay = 'y'
while continuePlay is 'y':
    restart()       
    continuePlay = input("Press 'y' for Yes, 'n' for No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function.

```
def my_game():
    question = input("Press 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors")
    if question is 'r':
        print('I choose paper, I win!')
    elif question is 's':
        print('I choose rock, I win!')
    elif question is 'p':
        print('I choose scissors, I win!')

    for restart in question:
        print(restart) # this command will print the string entered by the user, one character in each line

while True:
    my_game()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should insert your `input` statement in a loop

```
question = ""
while(question != 'e'):
    question = input("Press e to exit")
    if question is 'r':
        print("....r")
    elif question is 's':
        print(".....s")`
```

Comment: who can explain me why someone downwoted this answer?